# Right split using awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a txt file filled with file sizes and full paths.

ex:

```
1 3788160 /nfs/extracted/UNENCRYPTED.bin.extracted/_0.extracted/vmlinux.img
2 5971656 /nfs/extracted/extracted/out_v2.1.3.zip.extracted/firmware.tar.extracted/_uImage.extracted/vmlinux.bin.30071
3 4202630 /nfs/extracted/v2.0.0.10/extracted/v2.0.0.10.zip.extracted/_install.img.extracted/package2/vmlinux.develop.avhdd.mars.nand.bin
4 117 /nfs/extracted/v1.0.0.14/extracted/1.0.0.14.zip.extracted
```

I'd like to print the second column and the filename (rsplit on "/") so that a[0] is the file name.

```
3788160 vmlinux.img
5971656 vmlinux.bin.30071
4202630 vmlinux.develop.avhdd.mars.nand.bin
117 1.0.0.14.zip.extracted
```

Is there an awk equilient to rsplit?

ex:

```
awk '{rsplit($2,a,"/"); print $1, a[0]}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk '{sub(/^.*\//, "", $3); print $2, $3}' file
```

```
3788160 vmlinux.img
5971656 vmlinux.bin.30071
4202630 vmlinux.develop.avhdd.mars.nand.bin
117 1.0.0.14.zip.extracted
```

Here:

- `sub(/^.*\//, "", $3)`: Removes everything upon start to last `/`
- `print $2, $3`: Print 2nd and 3rd column

Answer (score 3):

OP almost had it, just 2 smallish changes:

- use the `split()` function (`split()` returns a count of the number of array entries which we'll catch and store in variable `n`)
- access the last item of the array (instead of `a[0]`)

Data set:

```
$ cat input.dat
1 3788160 /nfs/extracted/UNENCRYPTED.bin.extracted/_0.extracted/vmlinux.img
2 5971656 /nfs/extracted/extracted/out_v2.1.3.zip.extracted/firmware.tar.extracted/_uImage.extracted/vmlinux.bin.30071
3 4202630 /nfs/extracted/v2.0.0.10/extracted/v2.0.0.10.zip.extracted/_install.img.extracted/package2/vmlinux.develop.avhdd.mars.nand.bin
4 117 /nfs/extracted/v1.0.0.14/extracted/1.0.0.14.zip.extracted
```

One `awk` solution using the `split()` function:

```
$ awk '{ n=split($3,a,"/") ; print $2, a[n] }' input.dat
3788160 vmlinux.img
5971656 vmlinux.bin.30071
4202630 vmlinux.develop.avhdd.mars.nand.bin
117 1.0.0.14.zip.extracted
```

Answer (score 1):

In native bash, no awk needed:

```
while read -r _ size name; do
  printf '%s\n' "$size ${name##*/}"
done
```

This throws away the first column by putting it into the variable `$_`; puts the second column into `size`, and puts the remaining content on each line into the variable `name`; then uses the [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) `${name##*/}` to strip everything up-to-and-including the last `/` from `name` on output.

Comment: @markp-fuso, there's no `input_file` listed in the original awk call, which is why I'm not listing one here. If the OP's original code reads input from stdin and writes output to stdout, it makes sense for answers to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, looks like this could be done with creating separate field delimiters tested and written with shown samples only. Written and tested in https://ideone.com/sk8zV1

```
awk -F'[ /]' '{print $2,$NF}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simply making space and `/` as field delimiters and printing 2nd and last fields as per shown samples. Note `NF` denotes number of fields in current line so `$NF` will print last field's value here.